# For loop in groovy with two list of variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy

i have a list of batch commands that performs xcopy 's, like this. This is for a jenkins pipeline script:

```
        bat "xcopy %cd%${some_path1}\\obj\\Lab5\\Package\\PackageTmp ${host1}\\dir1 /E /Y /V"
        bat "xcopy %cd%${some_path2}\\obj\\Lab5\\Package\\PackageTmp ${host1}\\dir2 /E /Y /V"
        bat "xcopy %cd%${some_path3}\\obj\\Lab5\\Package\\PackageTmp ${host1}\\dir3 /E /Y /V"
```

How do i use a loop in groovy, so that i can have only one line of the batch command and pass the value of the variables `("some_path1", "some_path2", "some_path3")` & `("dir1", "dir2", "dir3")`

Comment: You also seem to have `host1` as a variable?  Did you mean `host` instead of `dir`?

Comment: Host1 is a variable that i have declared already and it stays constant for the list of commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, given a list of paths:

```
def paths = ['some_path1', 'some_path2', 'another_path']
```

And a list of directories for each path (in a 1:1 relationship)

```
def dirs = ['dir1', 'dir_for_some_path2', 'another_dir']
```

You can then do:

```
[paths, dirs].transpose().each { path, dir ->
    bat "xcopy %cd%${path}\\obj\\Lab5\\Package\\PackageTmp host1\\${dir} /E /Y /V"
}
```

In case you have an ancient version of groovy, try

```
[paths, dirs].transpose().each { pd ->
    def path = pd[0]
    def dir = pd[1]
    bat "xcopy %cd%${path}\\obj\\Lab5\\Package\\PackageTmp host1\\${dir} /E /Y /V"
}
```

Comment: (typo, maybe?) you might need to use ${paths} instead of ${path} in the command below: bat "xcopy %cd%${path}\\obj\\Lab5\\Package\\PackageTmp host1\\${dir} /E /Y /V"

Comment: ahh!! i see with the each, the variable name have been assigned as path. thanks

Comment: i am going to test it now, will update soon with the results

Comment: it doesn't work. below is what it returns on the console.     xcopy c:\myworkspace\test[folder1, dst1] C:\null /E /Y /V 
Invalid number of parameters

Comment: What version of groovy? I suspect old

Comment: i am executing the script through jenkins. I am not sure what is the version of groovy in my jenkins 1.643. Is there an interactive executor for groovy like the irb for Ruby?

Comment: Added a different version to the end of my answer, can you try that?

Comment: the later nailed it ... :)

Comment: Cool! Glad I could help! Good luck and have fun!

Comment: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/plugins/servlet/mobile#issue/JENKINS-26481.  This is the issue with jenkins